# Saving Data to a Database (Single Table) C#

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010, ms-access, save

I have been following the documentation here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f92s97z%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

However, I cannot get my application to work!

**please see my short video:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zpOCaT6NaGs

My Application is not working, I am having nightmares trying to get it working.

I want to make a 'Stock management System',

**Requirements:**

1. Browse through products (Name, Price)
2. Add Products to the Table
3. Edit Existing Products
4. Remove Existing Products
5. Save changes to the Table
6. Create an Order form that will allow for listing selected products and providing a quantity selected and cost displayed
7. Print the results.

I cannot seem to get the data to save to the database table without problems.

**My System:**

Windows 7 - SP1
Visual Studio 2010 Professional
Using a Microsoft Access Database (DataSet)
1 Table to connect
3 fields: "ID, proName, proPrice"

Any Help is very welcome, Thanks.

**My Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace KanadaStockControl
{
    public partial class frmProducts : Form
    {
        stockDataSet dsoc;
        OleDbConnection conn;
        OleDbDataAdapter da;

        public frmProducts()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ////Adding the items to the database
            //dboKanadaDataSetProducts.ProductsRow newProductsRow;
            //newProductsRow = dboKanadaDataSetProducts.Products.NewProductsRow();
            ////Setting the Product Name
            //newProductsRow.ProductName = txtItem.Text;
            ////Setting the Product Price
            //newProductsRow.ListPrice = txtPrice.Text;
            ////Adding the new row to the table
            //this.dboKanadaDataSetProducts.Products.Rows.Add(newProductsRow);
            ////Saving the new row to the database
            //this.productsTableAdapter.Update(this.dboKanadaDataSetProducts.Products);            
            //Old NON WORKING DATABASE ADD CODE:
            //dboKanadaDataSetProductsTableAdapters.ProductsTableAdapter productsTableAdapter = new dboKanadaDataSetProductsTableAdapters.ProductsTableAdapter();
            //productsTableAdapter.Insert("9", "NA", "0", txtPrice.Text, "Software");

            //lstPrice.Items.Add(txtPrice.Text);
            //lstItem.Items.Add(txtItem.Text);
            stockDataSetTableAdapters.stockTableAdapter stockTableAdaptor = new stockDataSetTableAdapters.stockTableAdapter();
            stockTableAdapter.Insert(txtItem.Text, txtPrice.Text);
        }

        //private void lstItem_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        //{
        //    int x = lstItem.SelectedIndex;
        //    lstPrice.SelectedIndices.Add(x);
        //}

        //private void lstPrice_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        //{
        //    int x = lstPrice.SelectedIndex;
        //    lstItem.SelectedIndices.Add(x);
        //}

        private void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(1==1/*lstItem.SelectedItem == null*/)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You must select an Item first, Before you are able to delete it!");
            }
            else
            {


                //Finding the row to delete in the database
                //dboKanadaDataSetProducts.ProductsRow delProductsRow;
                //delProductsRow = dboKanadaDataSetProducts.Products.FindByProductsID(string ProductName);

                //START -------
                // Locate the row to delete.
                //NorthwindDataSet.RegionRow oldRegionRow;
                //oldRegionRow = northwindDataSet.Region.FindByRegionID(5);

                // Delete the row from the dataset
                //oldRegionRow.Delete();

                // Delete the row from the database 
                //this.regionTableAdapter.Update(this.northwindDataSet.Region);
                //END -------

                //lstPrice.Items.Remove(lstPrice.SelectedItem);
                //lstItem.Items.Remove(lstItem.SelectedItem);
            }
        }
//I cannot be bothered to add spaces to this code, hence the misaligned code.
    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //lstItem.Items.Clear();
        //lstPrice.Items.Clear();
    }

    private void txtPrice_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //string context = this.txtPrice.Text;
        //for (int i = 0; i < context.Length; i++)
        //{
        //    if (!char.IsNumber(context[i]))
        //    {
        //        MessageBox.Show("Only numbers are allowed in this field!");
        //        txtPrice.Text = txtPrice.Text.Remove(txtPrice.TextLength - 1);
        //    }
        //}
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /*
        if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure that you want to DELETE ALL LISTED ITEMS?", "WARNING: Delete All Records",
     MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
     == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            int j = lstPrice.Items.Count;
            for (int i = lstItem.Items.Count; i > 0; )
            {

                lstItem.Items.Remove(lstItem.Items[--i]);
                lstPrice.Items.Remove(lstPrice.Items[--j]);
            }
        }*/
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        frmOrder makeOrder = new frmOrder();
        makeOrder.Show();
    }

    //private void frmProducts_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    //{
    //    // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'dboKanadaDataSetProducts.Products' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    //    //this.productsTableAdapter.Fill(this.dboKanadaDataSetProducts.Products);

    //}

    private void frmProducts_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'stockDataSet.stock' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        //this.stockTableAdapter.Fill(this.stockDataSet.stock);
        dsoc = new stockDataSet();
        conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\stock.accdb");
        da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from stock", conn);
        OleDbCommandBuilder cmdBl = new OleDbCommandBuilder(da);
        da.Fill(dsoc, "stock");
        dataGridView2.DataSource = dsoc;
        dataGridView2.DataMember = "stock";
    }


    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //this.Validate();
            //this.stockBindingSource.EndEdit();
            //this.stockTableAdapter.Update(this.stockDataSet.stock);
            //MessageBox.Show("Update successful");
            //da.Update(stockDataSet.Tables["stock"]);

            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection oledb1 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\stock.accdb");
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT stock (proName, proPrice) VALUES ("+ txtItem.Text +", " + txtPrice.Text + ")";
            cmd.Connection = oledb1;

            oledb1.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            oledb1.Close();

        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Update failed");
        }



        //this.dataGridView1.EndEdit();
    }

    private void btnMenu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        frmMenu showMenu = new frmMenu();
        showMenu.Show();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You have to tell us the specific problem. "It doesn't work" and "problems" are not helpful to people who want to help you. Please include the specific errors you are getting.

Comment: Watch youtube video supplied in the original post

Comment: I would just like to know how to integrate an access database with visual studio 2010, so that I can do as directed in the numerical steps above.

Comment: I am not getting any errors, however, I am not getting any results (due to poor knowledge in C#, I will add in the code...

Answer (score 0):

cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO stock (proName, proPrice) VALUES ("+ txtItem.Text +", " + txtPrice.Text + ")";

Comment: I thought you'd need to either replace the inner-string quotation marks to singular quotation or to escape the the double quotes within the string. Otherwise the function will no execute correctly?

Answer (score -2):

It will work. But the data will be saved as a copy of database in the `bin/debug` folder.

Go to Solution explorer and change the properties of Database. Set `"Copy to output Directory=Copy if newer"` and then try. Good luck.